# Utilizar caracteres universales en identificadores gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

Viendo que https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/cpp/Implementation_002ddefined-behavior.html dice:
"GCC currently only permits universal character names if -fextended-identifiers is used, because the implementation of universal character names in identifiers is experimental."

Osea que se pueden usar cáracteres universales en identificadores utilizando la opción "-fextended-identifiers" quise probarlo yo mismo de forma bastante simple pero no funcionó.
Lo que intenté fue lo siguiente:

```
//prueba_identificador.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int máximo = 5;
    std::cout << máximo << std::endl;
}
```

Y después:

```
g++ -fextended-identifiers prueba_identificador.cpp
```

Pero me da el error:

```
prueba_identificador.cpp:3:7: error: stray ‘\303’ in program
    3 |  int m��ximo = 5;
      |       ^
prueba_identificador.cpp:3:8: error: stray ‘\241’ in program
    3 |  int m��ximo = 5;
      |        ^
prueba_identificador.cpp:4:16: error: stray ‘\303’ in program
    4 |  std::cout << m��ximo << std::endl;
      |                ^
prueba_identificador.cpp:4:17: error: stray ‘\241’ in program
    4 |  std::cout << m��ximo << std::endl;
      |                 ^
prueba_identificador.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prueba_identificador.cpp:3:9: error: expected initializer before ‘ximo’
    3 |  int máximo = 5;
      |         ^~~~
prueba_identificador.cpp:4:15: error: ‘m’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘tm’?
    4 |  std::cout << máximo << std::endl;
      |               ^
      |               tm
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Con caracteres universales se refieren a Unicode,¿cierto?
Según sublime text mi "prueba_identificador.cpp" usa UTF-8, el código fue ejecutado desde una distribución GNU/Linux usando gcc 9.4.0

Edit:
aclaración el link: gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/cpp/… habla sobre GCC 4.1.0 y yo estaba usando 9.4.0 donde -fextended-identifiers esta activado por defecto.

Comment: Aparentemente [todavía no está implementado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32799349/13419694). Clang si lo permite.

Comment: @Mateo Mil gracias, con ese enlace pude encontrar la información al respecto.
¿ Pongo un comentario dando una explicación reducida de la cuestión ? Digo más que nada porque todos los link al respecto están en inglés.

Comment: Si la pregunta no tiene respuestas y encontraste la solución, puedes hacer tu propia respuesta así le ayuda a las personas que tengan el mismo problema.

Comment: La pregunta tiene respuesta y esta en el link que enviaste. Osea, esto es básicamente un duplicado. Y no se sí la politica en estos casos es cerrar el hilo, e indicar que es un duplicado de ese otro hilo o, como este hilo esta en español y el otro en inglés, la política es diferente.

Comment: No, duplicado de considera si ya hay una pregunta similar con respuestas en el mismo sitio. [es.so] es independiente de [so].

Comment: Aaaah, ok. Entonces en un rato pongo la respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con "universal character names" https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/cpp/Implementation_002ddefined-behavior.html se refiere a los nombres de carácter universal, que son caracteres escritos de la forma \uNNNN (más información [acá](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-170))

Entonces lo que sí esta permitido es:

```
//prueba_identificador.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int m\u00E1ximo = 5;
    std::cout << m\u00E1ximo << std::endl;
}
```

00E1 es el unicode para "á".
Para que el primer ejemplo de código que dí en la pregunta funcionase sin más gcc debería soportar la utilización de UTF-8 en identificadores. Cosa que no hacía en GCC 9.4.0 y anteriores. A partir de GCC 10 ya sí.

Si de todas formas queres usar una declaración/definición en una versión anterior a la 10 de GCC cómo "int máximo = 5" como la que mostré en la pregunta, en los [FAQ de GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#utf8_identifiers) se muestra una forma (en "What is the status of adding the UTF-8 support for identifier names in GCC?")
Adaptado a mi código de ejemplo sería simplemente cambiar el archivo UCN_almost_UTF8_identifiers.cpp, quedaría algo así:

```
//file UCN_almost_UTF8_identifiers.cpp

#include<iostream>
int main() {
    int máximo = 5;
    std::cout << máximo << std::endl;
}
// with following makefile:

UCN_almost_UTF8_identifiers: UCN_almost_UTF8_identifiers.cpp
    to_UCN.sh UCN_almost_UTF8_identifiers.cpp
    g++ -fextended-identifiers -o UCN_almost_UTF8_identifiers /tmp/UCN_almost_UTF8_identifiers.cpp

//and the helper script: to_UCN.sh:

#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | perl -pe 'BEGIN { binmode STDIN, ":utf8"; } s/(.)/ord($1) < 128 ? $1 : sprintf("\\U%08x", ord($1))/ge;' > /tmp/$1
```

Si estás copiando y pegando para probarlo cambiá los espacios en el makefile por tabulaciones, sino make te va a tirar un error.
Para consultar exactamente que nombres de carácter universal son válidos en identificadores en gcc podes consultar este [enlace](https://repo.or.cz/w/official-gcc.git/blob/5b9a8c31af0e7d0f743e8ba07a3bbe03042f5869:/libcpp/ucnid.tab).

Clang por otro lado, tal como menciono @Mateo, no tiene problemas con usar caracteres encodeados en UTF-8 en los identificadores desde hace ya bastante tiempo creo. Entonces "prueba_identificador.cpp" tal cual lo puse en la pregunta debería funcionar sin más con clang.